# Filter array based on each letter in the search string

Tags: react-native

Take the code below which works fine:

```
function Test() {
  const txt = 'a'
  const fruit = [
    { name: 'apple' },
    { name: 'orange' },
    { name: 'kiwi' },
    { name: 'banana' },
    { name: 'lemon' },
  ]

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={fruit.filter((item) => String(item.name).includes(txt))}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
    />
  )
}

export default Test
```

The search string (***txt***) is `a` so the output would be:

```
apple
orange
banana
```

So far so good, now I want to be able to type for example `ae` and get all the items in the array that include both `a` and `e` in any order, not just `ae` together. here is the expected result for `const txt = 'ae'`:

```
apple
orange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to split the word characters and then on the filter check all of them with [array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const txt = 'ae'
const fruit = [
    { name: 'apple' },
    { name: 'orange' },
    { name: 'kiwi' },
    { name: 'banana' },
    { name: 'lemon' },
]

const search = (arr, str) => {
   const chars = str.split('');
   return arr.filter(
      item => chars.every(char => item.name.includes(char)) );
}

console.log(search(fruit, txt) )
```

Comment: Thank you! The code is so short and clean, however, it should not show banana or lemon, because they need to have both a and e

Comment: I did not notice that requirement. sorry.
So instead of `some` use `every`
(I fixed the answer accordingly)

Comment: OMG! This should have been the selected answer since it is much shorter and more robust. Thank you So much for your kind time and efforts, now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
  function Test() {
      const txt = 'a'
      const fruit = [
        { name: 'apple' },
        { name: 'orange' },
        { name: 'kiwi' },
        { name: 'banana' },
        { name: 'lemon' },
      ]


const searchFinal = () => {
        const newSplitSearch = txt.split("");
        const finalArray = []
        fruit.map((data) => {
    
          const nameData = data.name;
          let shouldBeAdded = true;
    
          for (let i = 0; i < newSplitSearch.length; i++) {
            if (nameData.includes(newSplitSearch[i])) {
    
            } else {
              shouldBeAdded = false;
            }
          }
    
          if (shouldBeAdded) {
            finalArray.push(data)
          }
    
        })
    
        return finalArray
      }
    
      return (
        <FlatList
          data={searchFinal()}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
        />
      )
    }
    
    export default Test
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Wow works perfectly! thank you. I wish there was a shorter way, but seems like there is not :)

Comment: Ye sadly not as of now,  will try to make it more performant.  Anyways of it helped.  Do upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `.includes()` method of the String object just accepts a string-type parameter to search for.

What you can do however is using a regular expression instead.

Most basically this would be:

```js
console.log("apple".match(/[a|e]/g));
```

The above would look for the letters **a** and **e** and return an array with the results found for **apple** `["a", "e"]`. Problem is it would also return something if there is three times **a** and no **e** like in **banana**.

To overcome this issue we need to clean the returned array from duplicates first and afterwards check if the number of elements is at least the number of unique letters we want to look for - which is 2 in case of **a** and **e**.

Here's an example:

```js
const fruit = [{
    name: 'apple'
  },
  {
    name: 'orange'
  },
  {
    name: 'kiwi'
  },
  {
    name: 'banana'
  },
  {
    name: 'lemon'
  },
]
let txt = "ae";
let regex = new RegExp("[" + txt.split("").join("|") + "]", "g");
fruit.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item.name, [...new Set(item.name.match(regex))].length >= txt.length);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is very informative. to be honest, it is a little bit hard for me to use regular expressions, I need to more study that. Thank you!